# Manually choose QUnit tests for execution

Tags: qunit, qunit-bdd

I'm using qunit 2.3.3 with qunit-parameterize. I'm interested in preparing a modal dialog html at start of the suite/runner.html which is used to select the test cases for execution. Is there a way to do this or any thoughts or leads around this please

Note: I found qunit.config.autostart(false) & start()/stop() for execution. But unable to call start() & stop() as they are not recognized as qunit functions. How to solve this ?

Comment: There isn't a function in QUnit to just start a given module/test. However, when you load the default QUnit UI there is a drop down that let's you select which module to run. All this does is reload the page with that module in the query string. So your modal _could_ do that, or you could just use QUnit's dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Jakerella, for thei info. I need to do exact thing at test case level. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: Ok. But thanks for the sharing your views. I finally dropped this idea & settled with using default filters - module drop down to run complete module at once & Search filter for particular to run a particular test case.